# Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in <c:forEach>

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, jstl, jsf-1.2

I am using JSF 1.2 in my application. I am trying to iterate through a String array which is defined in my backing bean like this:

```
private String[] services;
```

Below is the managed bean entry in faces-config file:

```
<managed-bean>     
    <managed-bean-name>registrationBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.bean.RegistrationBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>        
</managed-bean>
```

I am trying to iterate through the services selected by the user and display it in my screen. Below is the code I used:

```html
<c:forEach items="#{registrationBean.services}" var="service">
    <c:out value="${service}"></c:out>
</c:forEach>
```

But I am getting the error:

```
Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in <c:forEach>
```

Kindly let me know how to resolve this.

**EDIT**

If I change `String[]` to `List<String>` then I am getting this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: wrapped Exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:156)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
com.icesoft.faces.webapp.xmlhttp.BlockingServlet.service(BlockingServlet.java:56)
```

Below is the Backing Bean initialization:

```
private List<String> services;
public RegistrationBean() {
    this.services = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Faces-config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
```

```
<managed-bean>     
    <managed-bean-name>registrationBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.bean.RegistrationBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>        
</managed-bean>   

<navigation-rule>
    <description>This will navigate to the Success screen.</description>
    <from-view-id>/registration.jspx</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/success.jspx</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<description>
    ICEfaces Address Demo
</description>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.application.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.validateXml</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.synchronousUpdate</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
  <param-value>.jspx</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.icesoft.faces.util.event.servlet.ContextEventRepeater</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Faces Servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup> 1 </load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.webapp.xmlhttp.PersistentFacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup> 1 </load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Blocking Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.webapp.xmlhttp.BlockingServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup> 1 </load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Faces Servlet Mapping -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Persistent Faces Servlet Mapping -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.iface</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/xmlhttp/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Blocking Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/block/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
  <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>


<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Try changing `String[]` for `List<String>`.

Comment: I tried but got an exception as mentioned in the Edit section of my first post. Any further help on this?

Comment: Are you sure your managed bean is created, the `List<String> service` is initialized in your bean constructor or in `@PostConstruct` method and is not empty and the getter is clean: `public List<String> getService() { return this.service; }`?

Comment: Yes, I have provided the backing bean initialization constructor as well as the Managed bean in the first post. Please check and let me know.

Comment: Are you really using JSF 1.2? This problem suggests that you're actually using JSF 1.1, or are running JSF 1.2 in JSF 1.1 fallback modus. The `#{}` is then not supported in JSP tags. Please list the JARs in `/WEB-INF/lib` and show the `web.xml` and `faces-config.xml` root declarations so that we can point out the culprit. the `UnsupportedOperationException` is by the way beyond me. This indicates rather classpath pollution with duplicate or incompatible library versions (which would also potentially explain your JSTL problem though)

Comment: Ok the jars used are :`jsf-api-1.2.jar` and `jsf-impl-1.2.jar`. I have `icefaces-comps.jar` and `icefaces.jar` also added but still I have not used any icefaces stuff in this project. Along with this I have jstl.jar and standard.jar added. Others are all commons related jar need by the Tomcat and `backport-util-concurrent-2.2,jar`

Comment: posted the web.xml and faces-config.xml in first post

Comment: If the problem is in your `index.jsp` file is because isn't matching with Faces Servlet mapping: `*.jspx`, `*.faces`.

Comment: I have this in my index.jsp: `<jsp:forward page="registration.iface" />` which redirects me to the registration.jspx file.

Comment: Are you sure the second problem is not a different problem that the one stated at the beginning?

Comment: Begining problem was for using `String[]`. Then based on your suggestion  changed it to `List<String>` and got the problem mention in the edit section of the first post.

Comment: I mean that first problem may be solved with the suggestion but now you have this second problem due to something else that is not posted here. It will be better if you have a clean page where you only try your `<c:forEach>` tag with the managed bean. If there's no problems there, start adding the JSF and IceFaces components to find the real problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't explain why you have this problem provided that you're on JSF 1.2. Most likely your project or environment is messed up with duplicate or conflicting libraries. Or your `faces-config.xml` is declared conform JSF 1.1 instead of JSF 1.2. Or perhaps ICEfaces played a role somehow, but I can't tell that as I've never really used that library.

In any case, I can explain specifically this problem when you're actually using JSF 1.1. The `#{}` is then not supported in JSP tags at all and the `<c:forEach items>` would produce exactly this error.

> Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in <c:forEach>

You should then be using `${}` all the time in JSP tags. However, the `${}` won't autocreate JSF managed beans when they are not present in the scope yet. In that case, the `<c:forEach>` would effectively get an empty collection and render nothing (but thus not produce exactly the error you're facing!).

So, you'd need to make sure that the JSF managed bean is already been autocreated before the `<c:forEach>` is entered. You can do that by using fullworthy JSF component like `<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty bean.list}">` wrapping the tag, or a `<h:outputText value="#{bean.text}">` before the tag.

E.g.

```html
<h:someComponent someAttribute="#{registrationBean.something}" />
<c:forEach items="${registrationBean.services}" var="service">
    <c:out value="${service}" />
</c:forEach>
```

A fullworthy JSF 1.x alternative would be to use [Tomahawk's](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/) `<t:dataList>` instead of JSTL `<c:forEach>`.

```html
<t:dataList value="#{registrationBean.services}" var="service">
    <h:outputText value="#{service}" />
</t:dataList>
```